# In vim in binary mode what is a ^K character?

Tags: text-processing, vim, binary

When I open a file with `vim -b` it displays `^K` sometimes in the text, which cannot be removed by `dos2unix`.  It prevents `dos2unix` from processing the file:

```
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x0B found at line 628
```

How can I remove them automatically (script or macro)?

Comment: That's a [vertical tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters). Of course `dos2unix` won't do anything about it, `dos2unix` only translates CR/LF to LF, it doesn't remove other control characters from the file.

Comment: But when it found it, it gnores the file: os2unix: Binary symbol 0x0B found at line 628

Comment: `perl -pe 's/\r\n/\n/' -i your_files`

Comment: `dos2unix -f your_files`